# How can I determine which properties in my model have changed using UpdateModel in Asp.net MVC 2 Preview 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there an easy way to determine which properties of my model have changed when using UpdateModel?  I am trying to record what edits a customer does to their record, say they login and change their phone number,I want to keep a record of that activity.

I know I could do it manually and just compare property by property but I was wondering if a slick pattern for that has been developed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look through [Controller.ModelState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.modelstate.aspx) for the [ModelState.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstate.value.aspx) property to see what was bound. Items not bound won't be in the [ModelStateDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary_members.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There also the option to do this on the database: [Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489.aspx)